# The expected value of the smallest number in sample $S$ is:

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, expectation

We are given a set $X = \{x_1, …. x_n\}$ where $x_i = 2^i$. A sample $S ⊆ X$ is drawn by selecting each $x_i$ independently with probability $p_1 = \frac{1}{2}$. The expected value of the smallest number in sample $S$ is:

1. $\frac{1}{n}$
2. $2$
3. $ \sqrt{n}$
4. $ n$

---

My attempt :

I assume $∅$ was excluded in $S$. Then,

$$ E = \frac 1{2^1}\times(2^1) + \frac 1{2^2}\times(2^2) + \cdots \frac 1{2^n}\times(2^n)= \overbrace {1+\cdots +1}^{n\;terms}=n$$

> Can you explain in formal/alternative way, please?

Comment: Is $\emptyset$ excluded?  for $n=1$ I'd assume the answer was $2$, no?  But you get $1$.

Comment: This question was from GATE $2006$, I've posted as that was. I need explanation for both situation when $\phi$ is included and not. If possible. Thanks.

Comment: As it stands, your probabilities do not even add to $1$.  $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{2^i}=1-\frac 1{2^n}$.  Either you add a term like $\frac 1{2^n}\times 0$, if you want $\emptyset$ to give you $0$ (in which case your answer is retroactively justified), or you have to divide by $1-\frac 1{2^n}$ to exclude the empty case.

Comment: @lulu, as weight is defined,

$$x_i=2^i$$, 

Therefore, one term for $\phi$:

$$\frac 1{2^0}\times(2^0)=1 $$

Resultant $n+1$. Am I right?

Comment: You don't have a term corresponding to $i=0$.  I made up the value $0$ as, in my mind, the only natural selection for the empty set.  You could assign $1$ to that case if you wished (but that would need to be made explicit).  Broadly speaking, I think you ought to either exclude $\emptyset$ or declare what value you want for that case.  Absent a declaration, I'd assume $\emptyset$ was excluded.

Comment: How do you define the "smallest number in $S$" when $S=\varnothing$ (i.e. no numbers are selected)?

Comment: I assumed  $∅$ excluded in $S$.

Comment: @lulu: I think the minimum of an empty set of reals is conventionally $+\infty$, which ensures $\min(A \cup B) = \min(\min(A), \min(B))$ holds in general

Comment: @Henry  But then $\max(A\cup \emptyset)=\infty$?  But then nobody said there had to be a single convention that made sense in all contexts.

Comment: @lulu: no - the same convention has $\max(\emptyset ) = -\infty$ so $\max(A\cup \emptyset)= - \infty$.  It is true that $\forall x \in \emptyset$ you have $\min(\emptyset) \le x$ and $x \le \max(\emptyset)$ even though that does not imply $\min(\emptyset) \le \max(\emptyset)$

Comment: @Henry  Yikes!  So we keep the union rules but lose the property that $\min(S)≤\max(S)$?  Interesting.  Unintuitive, but interesting.  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Sorry - I should have typed $\max(\emptyset)=-\infty$ so $\max(A\cup\emptyset)=\max(A)$

Comment: Each $x_i$ is the minimum of $S$ if one decides to include $x_i$ and to exclude each $x_j$ with $j<i$, which happens with probability $p_i=2^{-i}$. Thus, $$E(\min S;S\ne\varnothing)=\sum_{i=1}^np_ix_i=n.$$ Since $P(S=\varnothing)=2^{-n}$, one gets $$E(\min S\mid S\ne\varnothing)=\frac{n}{1-2^{-n}}.$$